# Norm function is proper on subsets of positive line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $L$ a positive line bundle on $X$. By Kodaira's embedding theorem, $X$ is projective algebraic. If $S\subseteq L^*$ is closed in the Zariski topology and disjoint from the zero section, is the map
$$S\to\mathbb{R},\quad v\mapsto\|v\|^2$$
proper? Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the fibre metric.

I know that this is true when $X\subseteq\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $L=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^n}(1)|_X$ with the standard fibre metric (giving $X$ the Fubini-Study metric). But even though $X$ and $L$ have to be of this form by Kodaira, the fibre metric might be different.

Comment: Denote that map by $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$.  Since $X$ is itself compact, properness of $f$ is equivalent to properness of the product map $(\pi,f):S\to X\times \mathbb{R}$, where $\pi$ is the projection from $L^*$.  The target is naturally isomorphic to the quotient of $L$ by the natural action of the compact subgroup $\mathbf{S}^1\subset \mathbb{C}^*$, for the usual scaling action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $L$.  This does not mention the fiber metric at all; it is simply the composition $S\hookrightarrow L \to L/\mathbf{S}^1$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Perfectly clear answer, thanks a lot.